# Access through a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

The implementation is through a linked list.  Would something like this be legal?

```
int val=temp.next->value;
temp.next->value =  temp->value;
temp->value = val;
```

Comment: The answer depends, among other things, on the language you're using.

Comment: Without context it's difficult to answer. However, you are using temp as both a pointer and a struct, and it can't be both. Please give some more context.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am in c++ and am using a linked list class with a Node structure in it.

Comment: you can directly write : `std::swap(temp.next->value, temp->value)`

Comment: please specify type of `temp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `temp` is a pointer, so fix `temp.next` with `temp->next`.

If `temp->next` is not NULL (a valid pointer to the next node), then yes, it would be legal.

Comment: if `temp` is pointer then you can't use dot operator with it like `temp.next` . Dot operator is to use with object/ref_to_objects of structs/class

Comment: I am just telling `temp` can't be pointer , you get this?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I don't get it? really? ..."it *would* be legal" (if he *fixed* it) (note: I bet temp is a pointer)

Comment: `temp` can have overloaded `operator->`

Comment: `temp->value = val;` and `temp.next->value;` can't be true at same time.

Comment: @Abyx even temp has that operator , it must be executed on class object.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: yes, we all *know* that. now *please* read my first sentence.